# MySQL table question. [MULTI PART QUESTION]

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if I allowed my users to pick which categories their post will be displayed in and they can pick multiple categories from one to many.

- How would I store the categories id value or values in the database?
- Should I group each value together for example, 45,12,45,78 or should I store one value at a time?
- And how would my table structure look like?
- Or should I add it to an existing table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you are describing is really a **[many-to-many relationship](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html)** (used in all tag-structures and alike).

```
Entries Table
+----+-------+------+
| id | title | text |
+----+-------+------+

Entries-to-Tags Table
+----------+--------+
| entry_id | tag_id |
+----------+--------+

Tags Table
+----+-----+
| id | tag |
+----+-----+
```

---

A typical SQL call to check on ALL entries from a tag would be

```
SELECT *
FROM tags_table as tg
LEFT JOIN entries_to_tags AS entg ON tg.id = entg.tag_id
LEFT JOIN entries AS en ON entg.entry_id = en.id
WHERE tg.tag = 'my tag'
```

A typical SQL call to check on tags from an entry would be

```
SELECT *
FROM entries AS en
LEFT JOIN entries_to_tags AS entg ON en.id = entg.entry_id 
LEFT JOIN tags_table AS tg ON entg.tag_id = tg.id
WHERE en.title = 'my article title'
```

Comment: The `id` field in the `Entries-to-Tags` table is unnecessary. Make `entry_id` and `tag_id` the (compound) primary key for that table.

Comment: @Jeff Mattfield, true! I've set it up on my own scheme for future revision control. Changed for simplicity. Thks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to design database tables is to separate them in smallest pieces possible. In this case, I will design it with 3 tables: Post, Category, and PostCategory.
Post will be the table for each post created by the user. 
Category should probably be a lookup table. 
PostCategory is the table to store each post's categories.

- Post is one to many PostCategory
- Category is one to many PostCategory
- PostCategory has PostId and CategoryId primary ids